# Python - EOL while scanning string literal of an Import statement

Tags: python

I am trying to test an s3 package using the command line, saying `py -c 'import s3'` and I receive an error for EOL end of string literal. Even though most of the other questions about EOL deal with not closing quotes or escaping characters, mine is a simple import statement. What could be wrong with the way I formatted it?

Comment: What happens if you start python and type `import s3`?

Comment: It throws an exception for invalid syntax located within s3's source code

Comment: So, you have to fix your `s3`.

Comment: So obviously there's something wrong with the s3 source code. Maybe you're trying to run Python 2 source with Python 3 or vice-versa. Maybe you accidentally edited one of the files while looking at it. Maybe you did something weird in installing it. Maybe you installed a never-finished 0.1 package that doesn't work. Without seeing it, or at least knowing how you installed it, it's pretty hard to guess.

Comment: Is there a BOM in the (included) file?

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing wrong with the source code (as far as i know), it's simply because you are using single quotes in the command line, which are not interpreted as grouping with spaces (on windows, which i can tell you are because you are using `py`). just use double quotes: `py -c "import s3"`. since the string is not being passed as a full argument, the python interpreter is just receiving 'import`, which is, as you probably know, not valid syntax :). if you want a simple program to show you why this how this happens in windows, i have this:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

on windows:

```
C:\Users\Michael\Desktop>py argv.py 'a sentence'
['argv.py', "'a", "sentence'"]
```

and on linux:

```
michael@Michael:/mnt/c/Users/Michael/Desktop$ python3 argv.py 'a sentence'
['argv.py', 'a sentence']
```

so, on windows, just use double quotes instead of single quotes, when passing command line arguments with spaces, because they will still be split on the spaces. on linux, it doesnt matter. once again, the solution to your problem is just to type:
`py -c "import s3"`
instead of: `py -c 'import s3'`
have a good day!